# Spring Quartz integration Quartz getting initialized twice

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, jersey-2.0

I have been working on integration our current project with Jersey, the webapplication uses Spring for IOC and Quartz scheduling. But post getting the configuration working I notice the following in the log files during startup:

```
2014-08-15 05:43:10,830 INFO  org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl.<init>:63 - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2014-08-15 05:43:10,834 INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.<init>:215 - Quartz Scheduler v.1.6.5 created.
2014-08-15 05:43:10,838 INFO  org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore.initialize:141 - RAMJobStore initialized.
2014-08-15 05:43:10,840 INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate:1229 - Quartz scheduler 'syncSchContext' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2014-08-15 05:43:10,841 INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate:1233 - Quartz scheduler version: 1.6.5
2014-08-15 05:43:10,848 INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.setJobFactory:2094 - JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory@210e5887
2014-08-15 05:43:10,995 INFO  org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl.<init>:63 - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2014-08-15 05:43:10,996 INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.<init>:215 - Quartz Scheduler v.1.6.5 created.
2014-08-15 05:43:10,997 INFO  org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore.initialize:141 - RAMJobStore initialized.
2014-08-15 05:43:10,997 INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate:1229 - Quartz scheduler 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2014-08-15 05:43:10,997 INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate:1233 - Quartz scheduler version: 1.6.5
2014-08-15 05:43:10,998 INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.setJobFactory:2094 - JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory@cd79d78
2014-08-15 05:43:11,795 INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start:461 - Scheduler     syncSchContext_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2014-08-15 05:43:11,796 INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start:461 - Scheduler org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
```

What might be causing this initialization to happen twice?

Comment: One situation that would cause the scheduler to run twice is if the bean that is bean scheduled in included in multiple contexts. Can you please share your bean and your Spring configuration?

Comment: @geoand you nailed it, i somehow forgot that i had two scheduling context filed.

Comment: I will add it as answer below for future readers to easily find. If it's not too much trouble, it would be good if you accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common situation that would cause the scheduler to run twice is if the bean that is bean scheduled in included in multiple contexts.

Make sure that the scheduled beans belong only to the root application context.